# Twitter Bootstrap 2.3.2 Carousel - changing interval to false does nothing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a carousel defined as such:

```
<div id="carouselGallery">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

And on a js - that gets called, as changing the interval there to a value such as, say, 10, does change the cycling speed - I have the following:

```
$('#carouselGallery').carousel({interval: false});
```

Which doesn't change anything at all; the closest I can do is change the interval value to a high number.

Comment: [Based on the Docs](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#carousel)  a number is expected as value for that option so if you want to set it **false** try with `0`...

Comment: Attempted that earlier; it appears to treat `0` as the default of `5000`.

Comment: can you recreate an example on codepen or bootply or jsfiddle ?